# Wordpress multi user

Tags: wordpress, authentication, messaging, multi-user

I have a site where I need to create users (apart from admin) and these users can login and exchange messages between them. They can also upload files that can be downloaded by other users.

So I am not sure if there is any plugin for this. also most important out of below two which is good option:

1. User can login from newly created login panel on "front end" and use messaging/file upload from front end developed functionality.
2. User uses admin panel login and after logging in see admin panel with some restriction, and here  can perform messaging/file upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [WP-Filebase Download Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-filebase/) plugin (allows users to upload files from the front-end) and [Private Messages For WordPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/private-messages-for-wordpress/)
 plugin.